# Store objects in local storage javascript

Tags: javascript, html, local-storage

I need to save some data being returned from WS call in local storage given certain conditions.  I know how to save the string keys, but I need to store quite a bit of data related to records.

How do I set to local storage as array of objects? For example:

```
{ID  : "1",  name: "john"}, 
{ID  : "2",  name: "dohn"}, 
...
```

Comment: Use `JSON.stringify()`

Comment: Use `localStorage.setItem('key', JSON.stringify(arr))`, replace `key` with the name of your key and `arr` with  name of your array